# How can I extend the Microsoft online token period?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, access-token, bearer-token, refresh-token

I get the access token as follows.However, the expiration time is still between 60-90 minutes.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&scope=SCOPE&expires_in=31536000" "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token"
```

When I want to extend the duration of the Refresh token; It also gives access tokens. How can I extend the token duration?

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=refresh_token
&refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN
&client_id=CLIENT_ID
&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
&scope=SCOPES
```

I tried to increase the expires_in time but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can set token lifetime policy but only for the access token. Azure AD doesn't support to set the token lifetime policy for the refresh token.

The range for the lifetime is from 10 minutes to 1 day. The default value is 1 hour.

Create the token lifetime policy and in the `definition` property specify the lifetime.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies
{
    "definition": [
        "{\"TokenLifetimePolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"AccessTokenLifetime\":\"2:00:00\"}}"
    ],
    "displayName": "2hours policy",
    "isOrganizationDefault": false
}
```

The response will contain the `id` of the `tokenLifetimePolicy`.

What is important to understand, **you don't assign the policy to your app but to the resource app/service principal your application is trying to access**.

Suppose that your app is using Graph API, so you need to find the Graph API id.

```
GET v1.0/servicePrincipals(appId='00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000')
```

The response contains `servicePrincipal` id for the Graph API.

Assign the policy the Graph API.

```
POST servicePrincipals/{id}/tokenLifetimePolicies/$ref
{
  "@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/policies/tokenLifetimePolicies/{policy_id}"
}
```

Now, when you generate an access token for your application, it will have the expiration set to 2 hours.

Disadvantage is that it will affect all applications that calls the Graph API.

Resources:

[Configure token lifetime policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes)

[Token lifetime policies](https://martin-machacek.com/blogPost/954be05e-6b06-44dc-9fac-408a629189ee)

[tokenLifetimePolicy resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/tokenlifetimepolicy?view=graph-rest-1.0)